# How to fix the cvhonor continuous from page before?

Tags: awesome-cv

In the CV template,

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/russelresume/zqnypvvjsfvq

I faced the cvhonor starts from new page, what I would like to continue the items to the next page.

You can see some awards can fit in page 1, but ALL goes to page 2.

[image]

[image]

I do not know who to place all the codes here. I have the minimum working example, in this link.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jph712yg5geqekndfq8sx/CVWorking.zip?rlkey=qqcei148xwucmwk0sskphtsis&dl=0